# Hyperlink Transferring from worksheet to worksheet

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2013, hyperlink

I am creating an excel file management platform for my staff. I have a master list created that houses all of the files that we are currently working on. Within the master list, I have the client's name hyperlinked to a specific folder on our public drive.

I have other tabs within the workbook that is employee specific. I am trying to get the client name hyperlink to automatically transfer to the specific employee tab and be active. I have used =hyperlink('Master List'!16), but the hyperlink is not active on the corresponding tab and returns an error Cannot open the specified file. It is still able to be opened from the master list, but not the employee specific tab.

Is there a way that I can get the hyperlink to transfer to another worksheet and be an active hyperlink? I am using the paste link feature so that if it is every updated, it will update on each tab as well.

Thank you,

Comment: Okay, I was not able to reproduce this issue.  It worked for me.  Can you reduce this down to a simple 2 tab issue and give us both formulas?  You can use "C:\" as the path.  That is what I did to test.  To be clear: Sheet1!A1=HYPERLINK("C:\")
Sheet2!A5=HYPERLINK(Sheet1A1)

And Sheet2s hyperlink worked fine, and changed when sheet1s was changed.

Comment: Honestly, this sounds like excel isn't the right tool for the job.

Comment: For Excel, you may need to specify a cell along with a worksheet. Yeah, probably a web page saved in MHT format would be sufficient. Or a readme.txt at the root of the network share.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Hyperlink to jump to another cell in Excel](http://superuser.com/questions/166417/hyperlink-to-jump-to-another-cell-in-excel)